# store jwt token in local storage through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, jwt, token

i need to store my jwt token in local storage and also get it back in the headers, everything works perfect when i test it with postman. i searched so much to find a correct way online and make it work, but didn't find anything useful.

**it the front end it returns the error invalid token or unauthorized user**

**here is my code:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('.submit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();


const name = $('#myInput').val();
const model = $('#do_it').val();
const condition = $('#select option:selected').val();
const description = $('#1').val();
const price = $('#exp').val();

const products = {
 product_name: name,
 product_model: model,
 product_condition: condition,
 product_description: description,
 expected_price: price
}

$.ajax({
 url: '/api/products_data',
 type: 'post',
 contentType: 'json',
 headers: { Authorization: "bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
 },
 data: products,
 dataType:'json',
 success: function(data){
             const dT  = localStorage.setItem("bearer", data.token);
             console.log(dT)
             alert(data.message);
 },
error: function (XHR, status, err){
         alert(XHR)
}
})
 })
});
```

i use express js in the backend

Edit:
**also my expreess jwt.verify code** may this help in finding figuring out the problem

```
checkToken: (req, res, next) =>{
        let token = req.get('Authorization') || req.body.token || req.query.token
        
        if(token){
              token = token.slice(7);
            jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_key, (err, decoded)=>{  
          
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.json({
                        success: 0,
                        message: 'Invalid token'
                    });
                }else{
                    next();
                }  
            });
        }else {
            res.json({
                success: 0,
                message:'Access denied! Unauthorized user'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put a blank between `bearer`and the token. Your code will result in `Authorization: BearereyJ...` but should be `Authorization:  Bearer eyJ...`

Comment: that didn't  help.

Comment: of course it helps, because without a blank it's simply wrong. There might be other errors, but at least it's one error less now.

Comment: exactly !  in that case of course it helped. may be it's in the back-end i just edited the post and added my jwt verify to see if something is there.

Comment: Can you confirm in the devtools network tab that the token is being set and sent to the back end?

Comment: it returns undefined in devtools in  and JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed in backend console log

Comment: i think it don't make it to the front end in the first place